# looping in javascript using array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have html code for input file, it have id and name

```
<input type="file" id="file1" name="my_field[]" class="image-upload" />
```

for validate input form, i check value using id but i have many input.

```
var count=0;
if(document.getElementById("file1").value != "") {
            // you have a file
            count = count + 1;
}
if(document.getElementById("file2").value != "") {
            // you have a file
            count = count + 1;
}
```

i want using getElementByName with array. this is what i have try:

```
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            if(document.getElementByName("my_field["+i+"]").value != "") {
            // you have a file
            count = count + 1;
            }
        }
```

Still not working. any suggest?

Comment: `getElementByName` is not a method of `document` - you want getElement**s**ByName - which returns a NodeList

Comment: thanks for correction

Comment: @NewbeeDev - it's always best to understand native js DOM methods before embarking on the sometimes incredibly slow path that is jQuery. If you know the "native" methods, you can avoid the parts of jQuery that are non-performant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have unique `id` values. Use those.

```
...
if(document.getElementById("file" + my_field[i].toString()).value != "") {
...
```